# Google Analytics: Real-Time Event tracking showing "phantom" events

Tags: google-analytics

In my Google Analytics Real-Time report "Events" I see events in the chart at the top. But the table below is empty -- no events with an event category.
So the question is what kind of events are shown in the chart?

[image]

Comment: Is this a new profile? Do you have filters on the profile?

Comment: Do you use _trackTiming?

Comment: It's a new profile, but not universal analytics. There're no filters. The website containes other GA accounts. But in none of them the "pantom" events do occur.

Comment: @Eduardo Yes, I use _trackPageLoadTime

Comment: I didn't ask about _trackPageLoadTime. I asked about _trackTimming https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiUserTiming

Comment: @Eduardo ah, sorry. No this method I'm not using.

Comment: @Eduardo I've removed _trackPageLoadTime and the "phantom" events are coming less frequent.